# Stream has already been listened to, error after change screens

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am applying the Bloc pattern in my application and I encountered problems when changing the screen by a Bottom Navigation.

I tried to make a Stream Broadcast, however after changing the screen the data disappears.

Here is my Home class, it represents the home screen.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final DepartmentBloc departmentBloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<DepartmentBloc>();
  final PromotionProductBloc promotionProductBloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<PromotionProductBloc>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomText(
              text: "Promoções",
              fontSize: 20.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: promotionProductBloc.outPromotionProducts,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData)
                  return Container(
                    height: 230.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 12.0, right: 12.0, bottom: 10.0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return PromotionProductCard(snapshot.data[index]);
                      },
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    ),
                  );
                else
                  return Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                  );
              },
            ),
            CustomText(
              text: "Categorias",
              fontSize: 20.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: departmentBloc.outDepartments,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData)
                  return Container(
                    height: 120.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return CategoryCard(snapshot.data[index]);
                      },
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    ),
                  );
                else
                  return Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                  );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the class that accesses the Service to get the data and opens an exit to the Stream.

```
class DepartmentBloc extends BlocBase {

  DepartmentService departmentService;

  List<Department> departments;

  final StreamController<List<Department>> _departmentController = StreamController<List<Department>>();
  Stream<List<Department>> get outDepartments => _departmentController.stream;

  DepartmentBloc() {
    departmentService = DepartmentService();
    getAll();
  }

  void getAll() async {
    departments =  await departmentService.getAll();
    _departmentController.sink.add(departments);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _departmentController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

PromotionProductBloc is the same as DepartmentBloc, it only changes Service access.

I'm using a Bottom Navigation, after going to another screen and back appears the following error: Stream has already been listened to.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```dart
  final StreamController<List<Department>> _departmentController = StreamController.broadcast<List<Department>>();
```

Seems like you are using a single subscription stream controller. They can only be listened once. An advantage of them is that first listener will receive those event that were emitted before subscribing to it. Broadcast streams do not guarantee this behavior but they can be subscribed to multiple times.

Comment: And to complement your answer, another good practice, in the future of course, it's to take a look in the RxDart library. Learning the three subjects will facilitate even more his knowledge

Comment: Broadcast made the data disappear when I change the screen. I think I managed to solve it like this: final _departmentController = BehaviorSubject<List<Department>>.seeded(List<Department>());